# Master-detail Filtering in SQL

Tags: sql

I have an interesting query that I would like to get done:
1. I have an **Article** table [ArticleId, ArticleName]
2. An Article has an **ArticleCheckin** (1:1) [ArticleId, CheckinName]
3. An Article can have multiple **ArticleResources** [ArticleResourceId, ArticleId, ResourceName]

I would like to write a query that gets me a list of Articles with Checkin (if exists) and a list of the Article Resources for each Article in the same query.
Currently, I obtain the Article and am querying the Resources again for each article and that doesn't seem like the right way to do this.

Any help would be great!

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK a query will always give you a flattened out result. This means that in order to get a list of Articles and lists of corresponding ArticleResources, you'll need to loop through each Article like you are doing now.

But you are not saying anything about which technology you are using, so it is hard to suggest how you can improve on your query/code.

Answer (score 0):

This query will give you all articles with or without checkins but only if there are article resources (LEFT JOIN otherwise).

```
SELECT A.*, AC.*, AR.*
FROM Article A
    LEFT JOIN ArticelCheckin AC ON AC.ArticleId = A.ArticleId
    INNER JOIN ArticleResources AR ON AR.ArticleId = A.ArticleId
```